# Music Player reading from text file plays all pieces at once Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, while-loop, media-player, thread-sleep

Hello I am currently trying to add music to my application and right now I am having the program get the file names from a file and play them. Due to a flaw in the application that I have tried mediating by putting the Thread to sleep the music player plays both pieces at the same time which while it sounds nice doesn't help me. Below is my code:

```
    public static class MusicPlayerService extends Service<Void>
{
    public static File[] musicArray = new File[2];
    public static int fileNumber = 0;

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask(){
        Scanner musicListReader;
        try {
            musicListReader = new Scanner(new File("Music_PlayList.txt"));
            while(musicListReader.hasNext())
            {
                musicArray[fileNumber] = new File(musicListReader.next());
                String uriString = musicArray[fileNumber].toURI().toString();
                Media media = new Media(uriString);
                MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
                player.play();
                Thread.sleep((long) media.getDuration().toMillis());
                fileNumber++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `media.getDuration().toMillis()` returning?

Comment: And there is my problem. Apparently it returns NaN instead of a number. What would that be? Null? And if so is there another way to get the value?

Comment: It's not null, it's `NaN`. See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Duration.html#toMillis--). You're trying to access the duration before the media has read it (it is, obviously, embedded somewhere in the metadata in the audio file). The sleeping loop is probably not actually a good approach: why not register an `onStopped` handler with the player and play the next track, if there is another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the looping-and-sleeping approach, consider using an event-driven approach instead. You can register an `onStopped` handler with the media player, and start the next song (if there is a next song) from there. This way, you don't need to use a background thread either.

Something like:

```
Queue<File> musicList = new LinkedList<File>();

try (Scanner musicListReader = new Scanner(new File("Music_PlayList.txt"))) {

    while (musicListReader.hasNext()) {
        musicList.add(new File(musicListReader.next()));
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

playNextMusicFile(musicList);

// ...

private void playNextMusicFile(Queue<File> musicList) {
    if (musicList.isEmpty()) {
        return ;
    }

    Media media = new Media(musicList.remove().toURI().toString());
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    player.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
        player.dispose();
        playNextMusicFile(musicList);
    });
    player.play();
}
```

Comment: Just wondering is there any reason why you wrote "This way, you don't need to use a background thread either." Is it detrimental to have it in a background thread or is just that I won't have to use `Platform.runLater()` when interacting with the interface?

Comment: @AdamRen It's simpler (so less prone to subtle errors). It's always better to avoid multithreading when you can as it's very difficult to get right. Threads are quite expensive too, in terms of system resources - there's a limited number you can allocate at any time, though that wouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: That seems like reason enough. What is the thread maximum because as I progress the application I will be using quite a few more of them?

Comment: It's system dependent. It's highly unlikely to be an issue in a desktop application; you are more likely to have to worry about it if you're writing high-demand server-side code. The main issue is code simplicity.

Comment: @AdamRen Hmm. Seems like it doesn't reliably transition to `STOPPED` when it reaches the end. I updated the code to use the current time instead.

Comment: Ok I tested the code and the problem is with `if (newTime.greaterThanOrEqualTo(player.getTotalDuration()))` for some reason this does not return true and the code is never reached after that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125161/discussion-between-adam-ren-and-james-d).